# add dynamic stamp at bottom of page to exiting pdf in nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdf, phantomjs

I want to add a stamp in exiting pdf that contains the dynamic date (only date in square box).

I used "phantom HTML to PDF package" to create pdf now on that pdf I want to add the date in stamp format.Can anybody please help me how to do this or any package to do it.

I stuck from last 10 days but not getting any solution. Please assist anybody.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you want to add timestamp to an existing PDF or to create new ones with the feature? Where do you want to place this tinestamp?

Comment: @Vaviloff, Thank You

Actually, I want PDF like http://66.235.194.119/pdf-test/pdf-make.png   .... I created PDF only left with stamp at right side in rectangle box with PAID ON date and date should be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have `page.evaluate` in PhantomJS we can do pretty much anything with the target web page before rendering it to an image or PDF. So let's add a stamp with the date of payment:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('https://www.google.co.uk', function() {

    // I'll just add jQuery for simpler stamp creation
    page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', function() {

        page.evaluate(function(){

            var date = new Date();
            var day = date.getDate();
            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var year = date.getFullYear();            

            var stamp = '<div style="position:absolute; right: 30px; bottom: 50px; color: green; border: 6px solid rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.75); border-radius: 10px; font: normal 24px/30px Tahoma;  transform: rotate(-30deg); padding: 15px; text-align: center;">PAID ON<br>' + day + '/' + month + '/' +  year + '</div>';

            $("body").append(stamp);

        });

        page.render("stamp.png");

        phantom.exit();   

    });
});
```

The result is:

[image: Result screenshot]